# Gpg4win Kleopatra v Gpg4win GNU Privacy Assistant

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

What is the difference between Kleopatra and GNU Privacy Assistant (both part of Gpg4win (https://www.gpg4win.org/))?

At first I thought GNU Privacy Assistant was simply a key manager (making it easier to manager your keys), however I have found tutorials on YouTube that explain how to encrypt using: GNU Privacy Assistant

I have spent time Googling this; this morning, however I have not found an answer.  I am relatively new to the field of Encryption.

Comment: You're not new to SO though, and you *know* that this is not a programming related question. You've got a whole page full of unaccepted answers. Maybe it's time to review the way you've contributed to SO lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_6.html

> - **Kleopatra** The central certificate administration of Gpg4win, which    ensures uniform user navigation for all cryptographic
>     operations.
> - **GNU Privacy Assistant (GPA)** is an alternative program for managing    certificates, in addition to Kleopatra.